# How do you hide a password in a program?

Tags: python, email, passwords

I am writing a program in python for a school project and one of its features is that it can send emails out.

However, in order to send an email from the program, you must login to the email account meaning my password for that account is contained within a variable in the program.

Because this is for a school project, I will have to send this to people I am working with and they'll be able to read the code but I don't really want my password being openly left in a variable for them to see.

Is there any way to hide it or encrypt it so that other people can't see it?

Comment: Why don't you create a test email account and then share it. You should never use your personal email regardless of whether you are sharing it or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

This is a big security issue and a very common way for people to have programs "hacked" (they post some code on a public repository with an API key or password in it, and people can take that and do what they want with it).

Here are the most common solutions to this problem:

- Use a server.  This probably isn't very viable for you since it's for a school project, but in larger project, we'd typically send a request to our server (which knows the password), and it would send it form there.  Code on a server (if protected correctly) is considered moderately safe.  Even still, it would be very bad design to put the password in the code.  Since the end user won't see the server's code, they won't be able to get that password.  Note that this is an oversimplification and there's more to securing a server than just what I've mentioned.
- Use environment variables.  Environment variables can be set in your terminal and store the information on your own computer, not in the program.  However, for it to work, each user would need to set their environment variables in their own terminal, and if you're trying to share an account, this is not the way to go because then you'd have to give them the password anyways.  [This](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) is a good article that discusses environment variables and how to set them.  In python, you can get the variable using the `os` module (`os.environ["ENV_VARIABLE_NAME"]`).

A general rule of thumb is never ever put anything in your source code (for the client side) that you wouldn't want the whole world seeing.  It is possible to get this information out of the code and can cause big issues down the road.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative and helpful. I think I will probably just create some kind of throwaway email where I don't mind the password being known, as this seems like the only viable option. Thank you for your response regardless though.

Comment: No problem @JamesL!  Good luck on your assignment.  If you found this helpful, it would be great if you could mark it as the correct answer!